# read in csv and changing first value from 'ID' then write csv in python3

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to import a csv, change the first value in the file, and then write the file out to another csv. I am doing this as excel opens the csv files as SYLK format files if 'ID' is in the first value. I therefore intend to change 'ID' to "Value_ID'. I can't figure out how to change the value of  s[0][0] = 'Value_ID'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
with open('input1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    s = ('output1.csv')
    filewriter = csv.writer(open(s,'w',newline= '\n'))

    for row in reader:
        filewriter.writerow(row)

s=[0][0] = 'Match_ID'
```

Comment: Here is a good example https://pymotw.com/2/csv/ if you still can't figure it out let me know and I'll code something up,

Comment: would you please provde your csv sample? and you want to change just first value of file which is probably first heading right??

Comment: you should separate reading from writing, it is unreadable

Comment: what this line `s=[0][0] = 'Match_ID'` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for doing this and many more operations quite efficiently and easily.

To install pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

This will make sure install all its dependencies as well.

Once this is done, open up the python shell

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input1.csv')
new_df = df.set_value(index,col,value)
new_df.to_csv('Output1.csv')
```

In the above snippet, replace your index with row number and column with the colomn name. 
If you are unsure what the row and column names are, type

```
df.head(5)
```

This shall give you top 5 rows and coloumns of the Pandas Dataframe. 
Happy coding. Cheers!